# The requested URL /users/login was not found on this server in cakephp project of ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cakephp, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, htdocs

I have upload a complete cakephp project on ubuntu server here I used apache2.

My project worked properly in my locak server(xampp) but in server it showing this error:

> The requested URL /users/login was not found on this server.

My project is located in `var/www/html`.

This is my `.htdocs` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/  [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I need a proper solution.

Answer (score 5):

Check that the apache configuration file has the rewrite_module line and that it's uncommented:

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

Also make sure your override and symlink option are correct in the above apache configuration:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
#    Order deny,allow
#    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Depending on your version of cakephp the .htaccess should like these.

**app/.htacces** CakePHP 2:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/.htacces** CakePHP 3:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**webroot/.htaccess** Both versions:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```